# NPC follow script does not run, and no error

Tags: lua, scripting, roblox

Here's the code:

```
local connection = path.Reached:Connect(function()
            reached = true
            script.Parent.Reached:Fire(target)
        end)
        repeat
            chasing = true
            followingTarget = target
            -- enable stuff for target
            target.GettingChased.Value = true
            target.GettingChasedBy.Value = script.Parent
            TeddyAI.Chasing.Value = true
            local plr = game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(target.Character)
            path:Run(target.Character.HumanoidRootPart.Position)
        until not path or path.LastError == "ComputationError" or not target.Character or target.Character:FindFirstChild("HumanoidRootPart") == nil or target.Character.Humanoid.Health < 1 or target.Safe.Value or findPotentialTarget() ~= target or reached
        if connection then
            connection:Disconnect()
        end
        if findPotentialTarget() ~= target then
            if path and path._moveConnection then
                path:Stop()
            end
        end
        print("stopped")
        chasing = false
    else
        print("block to block")
        blockToBlock()
    end
    game:GetService("RunService").Heartbeat:Wait()
end
```

all the other functions like "findPotentialTarget()" are functions that I declared, and I hope that they aren't the issue. If it is neccesary, I will post their code too.

I tried trying to define a function (local function.....) but that did not work out. The code I posted is supposed to make my model go towards the player, but does not work at all.

Comment: `Why does this not work?` Well, what is the effect required?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the complete code and the context in which this code is used, it's difficult to pinpoint the exact problem. However, I can suggest some steps you can take to fix the problem.

Check for syntax errors.
Make sure your code does not contain any syntax errors. Even a small typo can cause your code to fail silently with no error message.

Check for logic errors.
Check your code for logic errors. Are all variables properly initialized? Is the condition in the repeat-until loop evaluated correctly?

Check the value of the variable.
Include print statements in your code to check the values ​​of variables at various points in your code. This helps determine if the variables are set correctly.

Make sure the functionality works as expected.
Make sure the functions you define work as expected. This can be done by testing them separately. Debug your code.
If none of the above steps work, use a debugger to step through the code and identify where the problem is occurring.

I hope these steps help you find the problem and fix your code. If you need more help, please provide more information about your code and the problem you are facing.

Comment: Would it help if I would send the entire code?